# C++ operator overloading return

Tags: c++

In this code:

```
RationalNum operator+(const RationalNum& left, const RationalNum& right) {
    RationalNum temp;
    /*code here*/
    return temp;
}
```

How can it return a RationalNum object if the object is "deleted" from the stack when this function exits?

Comment: Make sure your `RationalNum` class follows the rule of 3 /5 /0.

Comment: @FredyR4zox, objects are not `delete`d in stack, but they are destructed when they are out of scope?

Comment: Cannot reproduce https://wandbox.org/permlink/BpySBdLYWcvRYBn0

Comment: *How can it return a RationalNum object if the object is "deleted"* -- The same way that `int foo() { int i = 10; return i;}` returns `10`, even though "i" is "deleted".

Comment: Since this is a by-value return, there's no problem here. In fact, with [NRVO](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision), chances are good that `temp` will never actually be created in the function's stack frame at all. If you were returning a pointer or reference, you'd be in deep doo doo.

Comment: Thank you all :)
I understood :)

Answer (score 7):

It is because the return value is copied (if necessary) before local variables are destroyed. And destroying the returned object is the duty of the calling function.

The returned object is constructed at the point of the return statement but the destruction of locals is left until the end of the block (which comes after the return).

Comment: Note that this is a copy elision context

Comment: "copied" or "moved" or "constructed elsewhere on the stack, because it is known the variable will be returned".

Comment: Thank you all :)
I understood :)